# Process names over 21 characters not detected/supported by TaskList

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want my batch file to check that the process name exists and is running using TaskList before continuing with the code, but unfortunately, it won't work if the process name has over 21 characters. Any way to remove the character limit or support process names over 21 characters?

I tried using any other process name with 21 characters or less and the code works flawlessly. I haven't tried anything else as I've been looking up online but could not find anything matching my exact problem or have no clue why it won't detect process names that are too long. I've reduced my code so that it is shorter and easier to understand.

```
@echo off

set ProcessName=PROCESSNAME

for /f "tokens=4-7 delims=[.] " %%i in ('ver') do (if %%i==Version (set v=%%j.%%k) else (set version=%%i.%%j))

if "%version%" == "10.0" goto win10 

:win10
setlocal
echo Press any key to start...
pause >nul

tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq %ProcessName%.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%ProcessName%.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
goto error
)

echo Process detected.
pause
exit

:error
echo WARNING! This process is not running. Make sure it is running or written properly.
pause
```

To test this, you can create a fake .exe and give it a long name then replace that name on this line:

```
set ProcessName=PROCESSNAME
```

I expect any process name with 22 characters and more to be supported.

Comment: What about [`wmic`](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)`Process where "Name='%ProcessName%'" get Name,ProcessID`? Anyway, the `/FI` (`/IM`) filter option of `tasklist` (`taskkill`) should also accept longer process names, only the display output may be truncated...

Comment: I'll try that. I don't even need to output the name.

Comment: You do not output on the console, but you pipe the output into `find`, so the returned text is relevant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BDM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2045818)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56572045) shows you how to achieve that `tasklist` returns also longer process names.

Just let me point out that the filter option `/FI` (`tasklist /FI "ImageName eq process.exe"`) does accept longer process (or image) names, only the returned text may be truncated.

Anyway, you do not output process names to the console, but you are piping them into `find`, so the returned text is indeed relevant.

But instead of searching the returned list of processes for the process names again just to detect whether at least one such is running, you could revert the search to capture the `tasklist` message when no matching processes are encountered by `findstr` like this:

```cmd
tasklist /FI "ImageName eq %ProcessName%.exe" | findstr /V /B /C:"INFO: " > nul
```

This, like your `find` command, sets `ErrorLevel` in case no matching process is found.

---

An alternative to `tasklist` is the [`wmic`](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) command:

```cmd
wmic Process where "Name='%ProcessName%.exe'" get Name,ProcessID
```

And together with `find`:

```cmd
wmic Process where "Name='%ProcessName%.exe'" get Name,ProcessID 2> nul | find /I ".exe" > nul
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change the output format of `tasklist` using the `/fo` switch:

```
/FO    format           Specifies the output format.
                       Valid values: "TABLE", "LIST", "CSV".
```

Changing the format to `CSV` allows for larger process names.

Try this:

```
tasklist /fo csv /fi "IMAGENAME eq %ProcessName%.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%ProcessName%.exe">NUL
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to get the processes using PowerShell.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET $ProcessName = 'svnserve'
SET "RUNNING=false"

FOR /F "delims=" %%p IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-Process -ProcessName $ProcessName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).ProcessName"') DO (
    SET "RUNNING=true"
)

ECHO RUNNING is %RUNNING%
```